# Outlook 2016 Spam Email

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

I accidentally marked an email as spam and it got moved into my spam folder. I have tried moving it back into my inbox but when Outlook syncs, the mail moves back to my spam folder. I have tried creating a rule to move it back into my inbox, added the email address into my safe senders list and also tried rebuilding my outlook profile but I still get the same result. Any ideas as to how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

#### Any ideas as to how this can be fixed?

You need to mark it as "Not Junk".

> A message that is marked as not junk is moved back to its original folder, usually the Inbox.

Instructions:

> To mark a message as not junk, do the following:
>
> 1. In Mail, click the Junk E-mail folder in the Navigation Pane.
> 2. In the message list, click any message that you want to mark as not junk.
> 3. On the Home tab, in the Delete group, click Not Junk.
>
> Keyboard shortcut: To mark a message as not junk, select the message,
>   and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd>.
>
> Notes:
>
> - A message that is marked as not junk is moved back to its original folder, usually the Inbox. If you have more than one email
>     account, the message is moved to the Inbox (or appropriate other
>     folder) in the active email account.
> - When you mark a message as not junk, you can add the sender or the mailing list name to the Safe Senders List or Safe Recipients
>     List.
> - By default, the Junk Email Filter is arranged by conversation. You can click the conversation header and mark the whole conversation
>     as not junk if the conversation isn’t expanded. You can mark
>     individual messages in an expanded conversation.
> - Any message viewed in the Junk E-mail folder appears in plain text format and any links that it contains are disabled. When a
>     message is moved out of the Junk E-mail folder, its original message
>     format is restored, and any links are enabled. However, links remain
>     disabled if the message is also categorized as suspicious.

Source [Mark an email message as not junk](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mark-an-email-message-as-not-junk-3ef8a89d-8c05-450a-9f19-9a1fbd94cb2a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

This is for  Outlook 2010, I presume it is the same or similar for Outlook 2016.

Comment: I came across that as well but that only works when the email is in the Junk Email folder. I tried moving the email into the Junk Folder and following the Microsoft KB  and the email got moved into the inbox but as soon as Outlook syncs, it moves it back into the spam folder.

Comment: @TeNaJSystems Hmm. Check out [Junk E-mail marked as Not Junk getting marked as Junk again](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/not-junk-email-marked-as-junk-again)

Comment: I checked out that as well, still same result

Answer (score 0):

Log into OWA and try to do what your doing on your local Outlook install.
1 - move the message
2 - look for offending or conflicting rules
3 - mark it safe

Make sure your local Outlook is not running while you do the above. After you do that wait 1 - 2 minutes then fire up your local OWA.

Comment: @chralyRoot, I followed your steps and I get the same results. There are no rule conflicts

Comment: Hmm. It's almost like you have a copy of Outlook running somewhere else. If OWA didn't do what you want them maybe it's a corrupted local install. Instead of deleting the local profile, try creating a new one, let it sync completely and then try to move the message and mark it safe. And don't open up the original profile at any point during this process. If I think of something else, I'll get back to you.